# C# .Net integration with Informix DB. Can it be done without the extra installation of the CSDK?

Tags: c#, driver, informix

Is it possible to connect to an Informix database without having to run the Informix SDK installer to get the driver?

I want to avoid any extra installation steps and was hoping there would be a Nuget package containing a stand-alone/self hosted driver.

Comment: I see lots of packages when I search for "informix" in the package manager.  Did you try that, and if so have you tried any of those packages?

Comment: Yeah I tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there were some plans to create a NuGet package with all the required CSDK libraries, but it doesn't exist yet.

You can install CSDK once, and then create a zip with the contents of INFORMIXDIR. The CSDK .NET provider will work without needing anything from the registry (assuming it has INFORMIXDIR and PATH environment variables correctly set).

Comment: sounds promising? can you ellaborate a bit more on how to do this? How do I reference the zip from my C# app?

Comment: J_S: Congratulations on reaching 1k!